# Downloading Files to Program Files triggering some Anti-Virus's causing failures - Can I do anything about it?

Tags: c#

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.DownloadFile(url, Path.Combine("c:/Program Files", "App1"));
}
```

for 100's of Application Dependencies at up to 8 simultaneous downloads at a time seems to be triggering Anti-Virus's in many different ways preventing it from downloading successfully.

---

Many of my users reported getting general WebClient exceptions (Generic "An exception occured during a WebClient request") as well as a Time-out exception (that isn't caused by a connection failure).

A lot of Anti-Virus's have "Web Protection" which I believe is causing these issues.

It's essentially a custom installer code-base that I created so I can manage how I download and check for updates how I like.

Windows Defender and Malware Bytes are shown to cause it.

As you can see, simply opening it triggered it and prevented the app from running at all.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLPWY.png
(MachineLearning/Anomalous.95%)

---

My general code process and flow is to read an argument and if it has /update it will do essentially same as installing just with some small changes. If it has /uninstall it will uninstall and without it at all, it will just install.

The app proceeds to check if the app it installs isnt open, it downloads a manifest file containing information on dependencies the app needs and checks them, if needed they are downloaded and ran.

It gets the main manifest which contains all files of the actual app, it proceeds to download them to the Program Files folder.

It copies the Installer exe to the Program Files directory as its also used for uninstalling with /uninstall

It then finally downloads the final file (.ico image for the shortcuts e.t.c)

Lastly it adds to the /Uninstall registry key to add to the Control Panel/Settings Apps & Programs as well as store a shortcut in start menu.

It then uses Process.Start to run the main .exe file it downloaded into Program Files earlier.

(If you need specific code please tell me)

---

Im hoping to reduce the amount of false detections its getting if possible or if theres any better routine to do here.

I'm trying to have it so I have a .exe that checks what needs to be installed/or updated without me having to update the installer exe but instead the 2 manifest (json) files.

---

Edit, after essentially stepping into my code by commenting out the entire thing and uncommenting small bit by bit, I realized Costura.Fody (Used to bind Newtonsoft.JSON.dll into my EXE) was causing it. Is there a reason why this occurs?

---

Edit 2, after removing Fody/Costura and manually handled the missing dependency with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` it barely got detected for anything at all, so thats good.

Comment: Code that changes the way dependencies are loaded will always be troublesome; it's one of the most common exploits for getting higher privileges. That's the main reason why Program files became a protected folder in the first place - otherwise any unprivileged code could gain administrator privileges by tweaking an existing privileged application. Downloading files directly to program files is a bad idea for the same reason - you need to verify the downloaded files before you allow them in the protected area. Installers don't belong in program files either.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for the explanation about the dependcy thing, but how can I essentially install to Program Files then and why do I require Admin Perms whereas other installers dont (yet they use Program Files too). And the Installer isnt rlly an installer, like it checks and grabs the files it needs (from a specific server set inside the code) and handles installing, updating and uninstalling.

Comment: Windows installers always need administrator privileges - the reason it looks different for your installer is exactly because it's not a Windows installer. The difference is that MSI has control over where you're requesting access, so it can prevent you from e.g. changing files in the folder of a different application; your custom application can do literally anything it wants as soon as you give it admin privileges.

Comment: @Luaan I see, is there somewhere else that I should use instead of Program Files to not require Admin Rights while still being able to throw a reg data for control panel + start menu shortcut?

Comment: For current user, all you need is user-level privileges. For all users, you'll always need admin privileges. I don't think you can do anything to the control panel with just user-level (I think it's always machine wide), but I might be wrong. If you don't need admin privileges, use a local appdata folder - it's meant for both data and executables. But going for a real installation in program files is probably still a better idea - if you don't have admin privileges for installation, you probably shouldn't be installing anything in the first place :)

Comment: @Luaan Current User installation is all thats needed. I can use Admin-Priviliges I just prefer not to require it. Any chance you can direct me where to check if editing /Uninstall Registry Key needs admin privileges?

Comment: Given that it's in the local machine hive rather than current user, I'd expect it to always need admin privileges; using MSI to handle the installation might help. Keep in mind that applications that are only installed for current user need to be able to be installed multiple times under different users.